# Loading Page Fragments with .load() excludes embeded javascript

Tags: jquery, load, parameter-passing

I have a form that is loaded using the .load() method.

```
$(function() {
    $('#items,#button-search').hide();
    $("#companies").click(function() { 
        $(this).attr("value",""); 
        $('#address,#new-company-form').empty();
    });
    $( "#companies" ).autocomplete({
        source: ";companies",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            if(ui.item.id == "create-new-company") {
                // call the new company form
                $('#address').empty();
                $('#new-company-form').load(';company_form #autoform');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#new-company-form').empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: ';addresses?company=' + ui.item.id,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    // process the addresses
                    success: function(json) {
                        var opts = '';
                        $.each(json, function(k, v) {
                            opts += '<option>' + v + '</option>';
                        });
                        $('#address').html('<select>' + opts + '</select>');
                    }
                }); //end ajax call to address
            }
        } // end select address
    }); // end autocomplete
}); // end function
```

on line 15, i have

```
$('#new-company-form').load(';company_form #autoform');
```

if i remove the #autoform the javascript that is in the ;company_form html works, otherwise it is not loaded.

how do i get this to work?

thanks

Comment: it is part of the framework i use. http://hforge.org/itools

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the `.load()` method is the url. The url that you need here is probably just `;company_form`. What do you want to achieve by passing `#autoform` in the url?

If it works without the `#autoform`, then why don't you simply remove it?

Comment: i need the #autoform because i don't want to load the entire template page

Answer (score 0):

Yeah he wants to load just the page fragment. The first argument is indeed url, so just put the name of the page that 'company_form' resides in then add the fragment you want. So it should look something like this...

```
$('#new-company-form').load('company_form.php #autoform');
```

I guess the only change is add the extension to 'company_form'

Comment: yes, i know. my problem is that any javascript that i have within the #autoform fragment does not work when it is called via the .load()